# VBA Export embedded video from Powerpoint presentation

Tags: vba, video, export, powerpoint, extract

I'm trying to convert an entire presentation to HTML, extracting all the embedded content etc along the way.  I've got text, audio, narrations etc all working fine but am having trouble finding out how to export video content.

Im looping through all slides in the presentation, then all shapes on the slide, looking for shapes of type `msoMedia`.  If I find one, then I check it's `MediaType`.  If it's `ppMediaTypeMovie`, then I can find the source file of an externally linked video file using `Shape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName`, but I can't for the life of me find out how to access EMBEDDED content.

If I find a shape with a `MediaType` of `ppMediaTypeSound` then I can use `Shape.SoundFormat.Export` to export the audio.  Does anybody know of an equivalent for VIDEO shapes?  (There's no `Shape.VideoFormat`)  I've spent days looking through every possible data member I can but to no avail.

Comment: If there is no way to directly access the video data using the Windows clipboard may help. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590595/extract-ole-object-data-in-microsoft-office-without-ole-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears Microsoft extract the contents of the media file to a temporary folder anyway, and embedded videos still provide a LinkFormat.SourceFullName to the extracted video:

`?oshape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName`

`C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.MSO\F26FF1D0.m4v`

All that I need to do is fire this file through ffmpeg and I've got my video, in the format I want!

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Note: You may find that the .Export method doesn't work for embedded sounds either in recent PPT versions.

Alex's suggestion is what I'd look into first; otherwise you can unzip the PPTX/PPSX/etc and find the videos in the media folder.  Or you might try saving as an XML presentation; you might be able to parse the video out of that.

Comment: Export works fine in Office 2007.  How do you unzip using VBA?  I avoid using Shell because finding the executable name for the app you're looking for (winzip?  winrar?  winace?  7zip? etc) is nearly impossible.

Shape.Export exports an image of a shape.  Works brilliant for images, charts, tables etc.  Shape.SoundFormat.Export exports an audio clip as a simple wav (which I'm then sending to ffmpeg to convert).  Why would Microsoft supply these methods to programatically extract images and sound, but choose not to do so with Video?  There must be a *proper* way!

Comment: If I were to programatically unzip and browse the contents of the ppt/media folder, how would I know which media file belongs to which Slide/Shape?

Comment: From my (limited) testing, it looks like the media files are sequentially numbered (media1.avi, media2.wmv etc), so you'd step through each slide, through each shape on each slide and add each media object to a collection or array; "media" & cstr(array_index) would give you the name of the media file in the zip; the extension would be whatever the original file's extension was, so you'd have to look for e.g. .avi, .wmv etc. or any file whose base name matches what you're after (ie, media3.*).

Comment: Unzipping using VBA: Agreed that shelling out to do the job isn't the best way.  I think 7zip may expose methods to COM control.  There other zip/unzip libraries that might do the job as well. Google Info-Zip and Advanced ZIP Library for some starting ideas.

Comment: Thanks Steve :)  Unfortunately, iterating over the shapes on a slide doesnt seem to happen in a consistent order.  I'm finding my output isnt always the same, even after running my script on the same presentation twice in a row.  (I haven't bothered researching this so don't quote me :))

Comment: Unless the slide is edited between runs, the order of shapes on a slide should never change (but you need to be looking at the index order in the collection, not the shape's ID property).  I did a quick test earlier and found that when the order of slides changes, the order of movies/names in the PPTX aka ZIP changes along with them - that's a GOOD thing.