# How do I extract files embedded in docx files in Python?

Tags: python, ms-word, ms-office, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am trying to extract files that are embedded in docx files in Python. I have created a simple docx that contains an embedded pdf, an embedded zip and an embedded docx to begin with.

I have been using the code below.

```py
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile
import pandas as pd

docx_path = Path('junk/test.docx')
docx_unzip_folder = Path('junk')

unzipped_files = []
with ZipFile(docx_path, mode='r') as zip:
    # locate all zip components
    for entry in zip.infolist():
        print(entry.filename)
        # unzip the zip components
        with zip.open(entry.filename, mode='r') as fzip_part:
            # replace the folders separator with underscore for convenience
            docx_unzip_file = docx_unzip_folder/(entry.filename.replace('/','_'))
            with open(docx_unzip_file, 'wb') as output_file:
                output_file.write(fzip_part.read())
            unzipped_file = {'originating docx': docx_path.name,
                             'unzipped file name': docx_unzip_file.name,
                             'unzipped file path': docx_unzip_file,
                             }
            unzipped_files.append(unzipped_file)

unzipped_files = pd.DataFrame(unzipped_files)
```

that works well in the sense that it outputs all embedded files as

- word_embeddings_oleObject1.bin
- word_embeddings_oleObject2.bin
- ...

[image]

By processing the information in the various xmls generated I can deduce the mime type of the embedded files and their location in the containing docx document. However, when I try to open the pdf and zip in acrobat/gzip they do not open even if I change the extension. The embedded word file opens fine.

Any clues?

PS: Please note that embedded word files behave much better because the approach above saves them with the correct extension, and they open fine. The issue is the pdfs and zip files.

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you consider using the Open XML SDK for dealing with open XML documents?

Answer (score 0):

To extract embeddings from Word.DocX you simply need to unzip in a working sub folder here using Windows **T**[ape]**ar**[chive] command.

[image]

Once extracted you can directly use the nested docx e.g. use it in write

[image]

However BIN files are actually nested [compound OLE.DOC containers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_File_Binary_Format) but cannot be actioned directly by word or write. their contents needs unpacking by different means. This issue has been described many times in Stack Overflow, but there seems to only be the suggestions you define your custom detection and use clipboard clippings for example see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71106113/10802527

The point to note is that zip and PDF must be handled as pure binary files without any bytes encoding, between a variable Head and a Tail that need splicing off.

For my PDF the start is 00002304 but for another 00002440 so not a constant.

[image]
[image]

For Python extraction there seems to be a proven answer here but unclear if it could be adapted for zip too?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56742848/10802527 however  note the +5 %%EOF may exist partway through the PDF **There can be multiple %%EOF in a PDF** so ensure you test it is the LAST ONE, and should include \x0A (a LineFeed)

However if you have inspected the files and thus know start address and length you can simply run [middle](https://blog.didierstevens.com/programs/binary-tools/) to save them

[image]

I have written a cmd script to extract my PDFs from the oleobject#.bin, so here is bin2pdf.cmd. It needs each filename to be called like `bin2pdf oleobject1.bin` and is only designed for embedded PDFs (not zips yet).
Dependencies are Sysinternals Strings.exe with Didier Stevens `middle.exe`. and no guarantee the maths works in all cases.

```
@echo off
REM dependencies are 
REM Didier Stevens middle.exe from https://blog.didierstevens.com/programs/binary-tools/
REM Mark Russinovich strings.exe from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/strings

REM both above to be placed on path or folder e.g.
set "utils=C:\Downloads\Apps\utils"

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
if not exist "%~dpn1.bin" echo %0 requires a bin file to work on & pause & exit /b

"%utils%\strings.exe" -o "%~1"|Findstr "%PDF-">AcroHEAD.txt
set /p HEAD=<AcroHEAD.txt
if [%HEAD%]==[] echo %PDF- Header not found & del Acro????.txt & pause & exit /b
echo !HEAD! >AcroHEAD.txt
for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%f in (AcroHEAD.txt) do set START=%%f

"%utils%\strings.exe" -o "%~1"|Findstr "%%EOF">AcroTAIL.txt
for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%f in (AcroTAIL.txt) do set TAIL=%%f
set /a LEN=%TAIL%+6-%START%

del Acro????.txt
"%utils%\middle.exe" "%~1" %START% %LEN% "%~dpn1.pdf"
```